# Oracle sql loader validation

Tags: sql, oracle, validation, constraints, sql-loader

I am using sql loader to load a csv file. One of the columns should be a Boolean. But Oracle does not support a Boolean datatype. So I need to add validation or a constraint. When I add a constraint on the column, it is ignored during direct load, so will need manual intervention afterwards to tidy up. If I try to use validation within the control file sql loader does not support the OR operator, just AND. so I cannot do WHEN colA='true' or colA='false'

I seen some sites had said to try something like the below, but the first WHEN clause was the only one accepted and ignored the second load.

```
OPTIONS (direct=true)
load data
TRUNCATE 
INTO TABLE TABLE_A
    WHEN PAY='false'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ( ID, NAME, PAY)
INTO TABLE TABLE_A
    WHEN PAY='true'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ( ID, NAME, PAY)
```

Can anyone provide any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL operators in the SQL*Loader field list to perform a CASE or DECODE on the value to convert it to in integer, or however you want to represent booleans.

Examples in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/ldr_field_list.htm#i1008150).

Comment: Thanks David, but I didn't want to change the representation of the data. 0=true and 1=false, will mean more changes at the application layer to change them back. Is there any other possible solutions?

Comment: I'm not sure what it is that you want to do, then.

Comment: I only want to load values which are either true or false into a table. No inbuilt constraints work when using sql loader and I cannot define the column as a Boolean type to reject them. So I need to write something in sql loader to achieve the logic. the CASE statement allows you to change the value if the case is match, but I do not see anywhere that shows I can write CASE PAY='false' THEN load INTO.... If you know of a way like this would you have an example? Many Thanks for your input David.